# More modular; include html elements in .js file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a page which has many buttons that perform an action with javascript. No problem here, just a html page and multiple .js file, one .js file for every action. Just to separate stuff a bit and make everything a bit more manageable. I will write a script to combine them all at deployment.

A lot of my javascript actions need html elements to function. For example to change a color the color.js needs a div with form elements so that user can change the color and press the button to save changes. The color.js binds functions to the onClick of the buttons and such. No problem here.

A problem comes up when there are many javascript actions using many html elements. All these html elements need to put into one html page. This makes managing things complicated. For example when i change the color field id i need to go to color.js and do the change. In addition i have to find the html element in my huge html page and also do the change.

Is it possible to put the html elements needed by my javascript actions into the .js file and somehow include it in my html page?

Of course i can escape all html elements and put it in a javascript variable and document.write it. But escaping is not a nice thing to do and changing html afterwards is quite painful.

I'm also not looking for a ajax function, cause with many different actions this will cause network problems.

Cheers for any thoughts on the subject!

Comment: Can't see so much code...What have you tried so far ?

Comment: If you want to go along this path, I would recommend using a library with templating facilities, like `Underscore.js`.

Comment: I would say try out angularjs or similar Framework you would prefer that handle nesting html elements?

Comment: Have you taken a look at React? Might be what you're looking for... http://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: Looks like what you want is to simply reference certain parts of dom in you javascript. Is that correct ?

Comment: Well, there are a number of libraries you can use, you don't need to reinvent the wheel. Knockout and Angular both react to stuff in your view, for example, there are also templating libraries, as well as just using jQuery to set up bindings to be executed when the page/elements are loaded

Comment: I would suspect that most template engines use ajax to load their templates, causing the network problem i described. Not really looking for an entire framework either ( sorry ;-) ), cause the need to keep things simple and integration speedy, maybe later though. I'm looking for a way to insert html elements in the dom (with posted restrictions see my post). Hope this explains things a bit more. Thanks for the suggestions though, i still going to look into them.

Comment: Knockout does have inline templates. Alternatively, you can define blocks of HTML to be shown based on rules - in fact, you can have both "visible" (if false, it has `display: none`) and a `ko if` (if false, the block is treated as not existing). Or there is the step away which abstracts this a bit and you can insert an HTML template inside the document and then refer to it throughout. If you are going to be compressing JS as part of deployment, you could also have the HTML templates defined in external files during deployment paste them into the relevant pages.

Comment: Peeking at Knockout!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **templates** to generate dynamic HTML via JavaScript. Most of **Templates Engines** have the same implementation:

- A template structure (DOM) or HTML string
- A method to render the template
- The data that fills the template (Array, Object)
- Settings to configure the template engine

I have used some template engines, one of them is **[Hogan.js](http://twitter.github.io/hogan.js/)** which has a friendly sugared-syntax, very easy to use, but lower performance. It implements the **[Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/)** syntax.

Other template engine is in **[Underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.io/underscore/#template)** library, which provides no sugared-syntax but a native javascript syntax, giving more power, and best performance.

The last one that I have used is **[kendo-ui templates](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/templates/expressions)**.
**[Kendo UI templates](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview)** have a heavy emphasis on performance over feature glut. It will trade convenient "syntax sugar" for improved performance.

If you want to try more engines, here you can get a lot of them:

- **[Template-Engine-Chooser](http://garann.github.io/template-chooser/)**

---

By other hand, if you want just to load static HTML (e.g. an static view), you can use **[jQuery.load(url)](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** to load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element. **[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** is a shorthand method of **[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**

---

**Recomendation:** whichever option you choose, I recommend using cache, either to save the view or to save the compiled template, thus the performance is improved by avoiding request of the same resource.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer, not much that i didn't yet know ( ;-) ) but good for the other readers. In the end i simply put my html files in /inc/, read the content of the files serverside into a string and inject string contents into my main html. Poor mans templating, but it solves my problem.